# Outlook 2010, looking for a smarter "not a junk" option

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, spam-prevention

Outlook 2010 marks some of newsletters I receive as junk. To move an email from a “Junk e-mails” to “Inbox” I right click on the email and then select “Junk” from a context menu, then click on “Not a junk” menu item.

While doing so the Outlook gives me an option to “Always trust email from” but unfortunately it would not work for me,  because the newsletter email address is not fixed due to use of a mass-email software.

I am looking for a option (or a rule?) in Outlook 2010 to automatically mark a particular email as "not as junk" based on a partial match of a email address to some text.

Comment: Is there any information that is common to each? (Phrase in subject line for example?)

Comment: Is "not using Outlook" an option?

Comment: @Austin''Danger''Powers no, the subject line is always different as it only contains a name of the article and no "brand" info whatsoever.

Comment: @Braiam I am afraid not, but would be happen to hear if you could expand your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: @Mitten if there is no string in either the subject, sender name  or message body which could allow a rule to identify these messages as non-junk, then I don't see how this is possible. Perhaps you can come up with a list of *multiple* words, each of which would only appear in genuine emails from this sender- and create multiple rules?

It seems a little strange that Braiam believes that the limitation here is with Outlook. I've never had a problem getting rules to do what I want.